# Building C# app

Tags: c#, appveyor

I've been looking to do some C# programming and came across exercism.io (which is a great way to learn a new language). I've downloaded their Hello World project which comes with a .csproj file.

I'm running MacOS so I can used `dotnet restore` and `dotnet test` to run my test. All works fine on my machine.

However, I'd like to be able to get this working on Appveyor as a starting point. When I try to run in AppVeyor I get:

> The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML
>   namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
>   please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
>   to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
>   1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

Incidentally, I get the same error when trying to open the project in Rider. The code can be seen at https://github.com/sjhuda/csharp-hello-world

Any advice welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason most likely is that the Hello World application you are trying to load is an Visual Studio 2017 application and it has a new csproj format, and from what I see in [this issue on Github](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1179) you need to pick the correct image.

Disclaimer:  I don't use Appveyor, just googled it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I came across that whilst googling and I've already changed the build worker image to VS 2017. I might drop Appveyor an email.

Comment: You probably set new image in UI, but when you have `appveyor.yml`, it takes over UI. So please add `image: Visual Studio 2017` to `appveyor.yml`